# How to compare directory listing against csv list?

Tags: python, shell, csv, command-line, automator

(In short, **compare csv list against directory listing and show results** good and bad.)

I am trying to simplify and expedite a re-occurring process.

I regularly receive multimedia assets (pdfs, word docs, pdfs, mpeg etc) to upload to a website CMS.  The list of the assets and the order they appear is determined by a csv file.

I want check the directory has the assets listed in the csv file before I upload (rather than try to import and find files missing afterwards on the clunky proprietary CMS).

**I am on a MAC**. I just want to run the process and throw the errors report back to the production dept to sort and resupply.

**Is there any way to automate this process through Automator, command line or scripting... or anything really?**

Thanks for your input in advance :)

Comment: It depends, what did you try? Using Python os.walk and file.readline, should give you the information you need without any fancy stuff, if what you want to do is just a flat comparaison. What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried any Python as I don't know any Python.  The tag was an automatic suggestion by StackOverflow - sorry for that.  Shall I remove the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your specific, bolded, question is

"yes, there are many ways to automate this, through command line scripting (bash), python and many others".

---

You should look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, in particular point #3.   As it stands, your current question is really a "help me with my homework question".

I have diligently answered the question you asked, but to get better actual help from stackoverflow, you need to start work yourself.

My suggestion would be to try python, though this is clearly a matter of opinion.

Your python code will look something like

```
import os
media_file_name = "media.txt"
media_file = open(media_filename)
file_list = media_file.readline()  # assuming its all csv on one line
for check_file in file_list.split(','):
    if os.path.isfile(check_file):
         print "%s is in place, good" % check_file
    else:
         print "%s is supposed to be here, but isn't" % check_file
```

I got this code by googling:

- python read line from file
- python check if file exists

Comment: You're shadowing `list` here... might want to rename to `file_list` or something along those lines (and if it is proper CSV then utilise `csv.reader` instead of splitting on `,`)

Comment: ROFL.   We meet again!  Are you stalking me? :D   With all that rep, you should just delete the OP's question, as "off topic" and put us all out of our misery ;)

Comment: Haha! Just look out your window and I'll wave! :p... nah, just relatively active in the Python tag and noticed you answering a few questions in it now, so thought I'd just drop some hints while I was about :)

Comment: Thanks for your input guys... I'll see what I can glean from Google.  The only homework I had done was trying to find a solution as surely I can't be the only person in history whos wanted to do this.  Also, I haven't posted before and I kind of guessed I would stuff it to some degree, sorry.

Comment: It's always good to be learning :)   One concrete thing to learn is that really stackoverflow is for questions about existing code, not for general "how to do" tasks.   Another thing to learn is that when someone give you a good answer, you upvote it, and ideally (if it is the right answer) you accept it.  That will encourage people to help you more next time.  Hint hint ;)

Comment: Thanks for the info, though my lowly reputation status of 6 won't let me upvote the answer :(

Comment: Hah - it's easy to forget who can do what :)   But ... you can _accept_ the answer.  If you do actually find it acceptable :)